# How to use exetended unix characters in c++ in Visual studio?

Tags: c++, encoding

We are using a korean font and freetype library and trying to display a korean character. But it displays some other characters indtead of hieroglyph
Code:

```
std::wstring text3 = L"놈";
```

Is there any tricks to type the korean characters?

Answer (score 1):

For maximum portability, I'd suggest avoiding encoding Unicode characters directly in your source code and using `\u` escape sequences instead.  The character 놈 is Unicode code point U+B188, so you could write this as:

```
std::wstring text3 = L"\uB188";
```

Answer (score -1):

The question is what is the encoding of the source code.
It is likely UTF-8, which is one of the reasons not to use wstring. Use regular string. For more information on my way of handling characters, see http://utf8everywhere.org.

Comment: what doesn't? UTF-8 encoded source code. Regular string literal. Should work.